# My textfield hides behind keyboard in BottomNavigationBar when I click to edit it

Tags: android, user-interface, flutter, dart, hidden-field

Im new to flutter. I am stuck at one place and I can't find the exact solution.

I have a BottomNavigationBar in which I have a textfield that needs input from the user. When I click on the textfield the keyboard covers up the whole half screen and textfield hides behind the keyboard and can't be seen. I want to move the textfield above the keyboard for better UI for the user.

this is the BottomNavigationBar code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  color: Colors.grey[200],
  height: 70,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 0, 0),
        child: TextField(  //this is the TextField
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontFamily: 'Karla',
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: 'Experimez-vous...',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

This is the main body (Scaffold) Im calling it from:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      CloseButtonScreen(),
      Container(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: HeaderContent(),
      ),
      ContainerListItems(),
    ],
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(), //this is where Im calling my BottomNavigationBar from
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionBtn(),
  floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endDocked,
  resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
);
```

screenshots:

the textfield is behind the keyboard in bottomnavigationbar

[image]

EXPERIMEZ VOUS the texfield

[image]

Comment: Can you share the complete code?

Comment: This is the complete code bro. I have shared all the files being used for the particular issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of struggling this is how I achieved it. Thanks everyone for contributing.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => {
      FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
    },
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CloseButtonScreen(),
            Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
              child: HeaderContent(),
            ),
            ContainerListItems(),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 90),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
              color: Colors.transparent,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: TextFormField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: 'Karla',
                ),
                decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                  hintText: 'Experimez-vous...',
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff2e3039),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

ignore the GestureDetector() widget.
Yes you have to wrap the body into SingleChildScrollView(), 
I was using bottomNavigationBar, had to finish that. 
Everyone contributed to my question were right. I just had to join the puzzle pieces accordingly.

I had to delete BottomNavigation File and include the code in the main body within a container.

Comment: Hello I have very similar code like this dont u feel lag i mean it takes like 5-7 seconds to come on top of keyboard even in profile mode

Comment: There is no TextField in this answer, whereas the question is specific to hiding TextField behind keypad.

Not sure how this is an accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve it simply like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Your title')),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Text('Add things that will be shown in the body'),
      ),
      //here comes your text field and will be shown at the bottom of the page
      TextField(),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: So simple and better. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In case this can help somebody else, adding a padding to the bottom of the container nicely keeps the bottonnavbar on top of the keyboard.

add this padding:
padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)
  color: Colors.grey[200],
  height: 70,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
      ),
      Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
        color: Colors.transparent,
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 0, 0, 0),
        child: TextField(  //this is the TextField
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 30,
            fontFamily: 'Karla',
          ),
          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
            hintText: 'Experimez-vous...',
            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Place all your widgets inside SingleChildScrollView widget.

UPDATED: Using Stack instead of BottomNavigationBar to show textfield

Comment: you should not place your textfield in the bottom of page by using BottomNavigationBar, instead, use Stack to position the textfield at the bottom.

Comment: I have places the textfield in the bottom now and removed the BottomNavigationBar but its still doesn't seem to work.                                here is what I did.      Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(.......ContainerListItems(),
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 80, 0, 0),
                  child: TextField(
                    style: TextStyle(.......),....), //singlechildscrollview

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it inside the **SingleChildScrollView** will allow your widget to slide up when keyboards appears.

```
Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
   child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        CloseButtonScreen(),
        Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
          child: HeaderContent(),
        ),
        ContainerListItems(),
     ],
   ),
 ),
...
);
```

Comment: bottomNaavigationBar cannot be wrapped inside the SingleChildScrollView widget. I have tried wrapping the main container in SingleChildScrollView but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just placed you every widget in `ListView` and use `shrinkWrap` property. Sample Code below:

```
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: new Container(
    child: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
      children: <Widget>[
        widget1,
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        widget2,
        SizedBox(height: 20.0),
        widget3,
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Can you share your code by uploading somewhere? Complete code

Comment: I can send u an email of the file (source code) I'm trying to make the change in, i:e this particular screen code...is that possible for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can change from `bottomNavigationBar` to `bottomSheet` but sometimes it will changed some layout you need to adjust it again

if you want to keep use `bottomNavigationBar` just add `padding` with `EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`